# Silverlight development in visual basic 2005

Tags: silverlight

is possible development for Silverlight in Visual Basic 2005? On the Microsoft website i found only the SDK for 2008.

Thank You
Alexander Nagy

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of tools you need to develop Silverlight 2 applications [source: http://silverlight.net/getstarted/]. Although in the past you could develop with VS2005 then the newest tools are only available for VS2008:

- [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc268305.aspx) or [Visual Web Developer Express with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/)
- [Silverlight Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=129043) for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer Express with SP1. 
  This will install the necessary Visual Studio updates, Silverlight project templates, developer runtime, and SDK. For additional information read the overview and the Silverlight 2 Readme Notes.

If you are just starting with Silverlight then I highly recomend also installing [Expression Blend 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5FF08106-B9F4-43CD-ABAD-4CC9D9C208D7&displaylang=en) with [SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=EB9B5C48-BA2B-4C39-A1C3-135C60BBBE66&displaylang=en)

As far as VB goes then you can definitely develop Silverlight applications using it.

Answer (score 1):

The templates for VS2005 are only for Silverlight 1.0 (Javascript) applications.  To develop Silverlight 2 applications *with Visual Studio* you will need VS 2008 (or one of the FREE express editions of Visual Web Developer Express 2008).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, i used before in the past, look for the SDKs and project templates they should be somewhere around

here is a link to [project template](http://ox.no/posts/silverlight-project-template-for-visual-studio-2005)